# How to change the cmd-h command to cmd-e

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I would like to make <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> do what <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> does.

I can do this in keyboard config, but I have to do it for every single program, as the title in the menu is "hide safari" for safari, and fx. "hide photoshop" for Photoshop.

Therefore I seek a solution, so that <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> does the same thing in every single program.

Comment: Cmd-E already has functionality assigned, I assume you are not interested in that?

Comment: i dont use cmd-E and i think it makes sense that: 

cmd+q is quit
cmd+w is close window
cmd+e is hide app

three combinations that are easy accessible with left hand, i cant reach cmd+h with ease :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [BetterTouch Tool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/) (free) or [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) (paid).

In BetterTouchTool:

1. Choose the **Keyboard** tab
2. Create a new **global** action with shortcut ⌘E and action ⌘H

[image]